# How would I handle checking for collision detection for multiple sprites of the same type?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm trying to handle collision checking on multiple sprites checking it against a player character. Here's the relevant code, the `Enemy` class creates a new sprite that is supposed to be represented by an image, and the `Character` class is similar, except it is the sprite the player can control. Here's the relevant code I've snipped from the project.

```
    self.all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    sprite = Character(warrior, (500, 500), (66, 66))
    enemies = []
    for i in range(10):
        enemy = Enemy("evilwizard")
        enemies.append(enemy)
        self.all_sprites_list.add(enemy)
    self.all_sprites_list.add(sprite)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
# This class represents the types of an enemy possible to be rendered to the scene

def __init__(self, enemy_type):
    super().__init__()  # Call sprite constructor
    # Pass in the type of enemy, x/y pos, and width/height (64x64)
    self.image = pygame.Surface([76, 76])
    self.image.fill(WHITE)
    self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = random.randrange(10, 1150)  # random start
    self.rect.y = random.randrange(10, 590)   # random start
    self.speed = 2
    self.move = [None, None]  # x-y coordinates to move to
    self.image = pygame.image.load(FILE_PATH_ENEMY + enemy_type + ".png").convert_alpha()
    self.direction = None  # direction to move the sprite`

class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, role, position, dimensions):
    """
    :param role: role instance giving character attributes
    :param position: (x, y) position on screen
    :param dimensions: dimensions of the sprite for creating image
    """
    super().__init__()
    # Call the sprite constructor
    # Pass in the type of the character, and its x and y position, width and height.
    # Set the background color and set it to be transparent.
    self.image = pygame.Surface(dimensions)
    self.image.fill(WHITE)
    self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(FILE_PATH_CHAR + role.title + ".png").convert_alpha()

    # Draw the character itself
    # position is the tuple (x, y)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x, self.rect.y = position

    self.attack = role.attack
    self.health = role.health
    self.title = role.title
```

Comment: if you use `self.image = pygame.image.load()` then there is no sense to use `self.image = pygame.Surface()`

Comment: Every time a sprite moves, it's new location will have to be checked against all the other existing sprites to see if the movement has caused any collusions to occur.

Comment: @martineau ive got a move method for the `Character` class like such and it checks if the `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` is near the borders of the wall before allowing movement, and the `Enemy` class has a roam method that creates random movement, would I need to do it in those areas?

Comment: Yes, _every_ time there's sprite movement that could result in a collision, checks will have to occur for each potential one. This means calling something like [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) for every pair of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame has [pygame.sprite.spritecollide](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) to check collision between `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` and `pygame.sprite.Group()`

It has also other functions to check collisions - see doc for [Sprite](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)